# How to ignore AWS Lambda timeout limit 300 seconds for long execution?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am stuck with timeout issue in AWS Lambda with Node.js which  default timeout time is 300 secs.

I want to download a `zip` `size>300MB` from S3 bucket and after extracting it, upload to in temp folder in same bucket.

But due to heavy data I am not able to complete this within time interval.

I can go with EBS but want to get any nearest solution which can work with Lambda function.

It'll be great if I can get a relevant suggestion to complete this task.

Here is the stuff which I have written in Lambda function.

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log('Received event for big file:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));

    // Get the object from the event and show its content type
    const bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    const key = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
    const params = {
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key: key,
    };
    s3.getObject(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error', err);
            const message = `Error getting object ${key} from bucket ${bucket}. Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function.`;
            console.log(message);
            callback(message);
        } else {
            console.log('Started to save buffers....');
            JSZip.loadAsync(data.Body).then(function(zip) {
                console.log('Started to extract files.....');
                async.eachSeries(zip.files, function(item, cbk1) {
                    if (!item.dir) {
                        async.waterfall([function(cbk) {
                            zip.file(item.name).async("text").then(function(content) {
                                cbk(null, content)
                            })
                        }], function(err, content) {
                            s3.putObject({
                                Bucket: bucket,
                                Key: 'bigtemp/' + item.name.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, ''),
                                Body: content
                            }, function(err, result) {
                                if(result && result.ETag){
                                console.log('uploaded file: ', result.ETag);
                                }
                                console.log('Error ', err);
                                cbk1();
                            });
                        })
                    } else {
                        cbk1();
                    }
                });
            });
            callback(null, data.ContentType);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Have you tried increasing the memory allotment for your Lambda function? Also, why are you using `async.eachSeries` which forces serialization instead of using `async.each` which can operate over each file in `zip.files` in parallel. The other thing you could try is to use streams: `s3.getObject(params).createReadStream().pipe(unzip.Parse()).on('entry', ...)`. `s3.putObject()` will also accept a readable stream as the value for `Body`.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment. I will update my code

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The timeout is imposed by AWS, and while it may be changed it the future (this has already happened twice -- [it is 15 minutes as of this writing](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/10/aws-lambda-supports-functions-that-can-run-up-to-15-minutes/). It was previously 300 seconds, updated from original value of 60 seconds) that won't help you today. Lambda alone simply isn't intended for long-running processes.

**Option 1: Migrate to ECS by emulating AWS Lambda in Docker**

Solutions exist to port your lambda function to ECS without having to rewrite your function by emulating lambda in a docker container. You can use [docker-lambda](https://github.com/lambci/docker-lambda) or [node-docker-lambda](https://github.com/tmaiaroto/node-docker-lambda) to emulate lambda in docker, and then you simply pass events via runTask.

If you end up changing your mind about wanting to maintain your lambda function, another example uses lambda as an event receiver and moves the bulk of the work into ECS.

Some example implementations:

- [Migrating Lambda to ECS](https://serifandsemaphore.io/aws-lambda-going-beyond-5-minutes-34e381e71231#.rzrp5wciy) - Uses the AWS Lambda docker emulator and triggers via runTask.
- [lambda-ecs-worker-pattern](https://github.com/awslabs/lambda-ecs-worker-pattern) - Uses AWS Lambda to handle S3 events, and writes to a SQS queue that is processed by an ECS worker.

**Option 2: AWS Step Functions**

If the timeout isn't bottle-necked on a single specific operation you may be able to split this into [AWS Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/), effectively turning one lambda into many. So one function would be calling S3 getObject, another handling the zipping, another calling S3 putObject, and so on as needed to get around the timeout. I suspect this isn't the case, but worth mentioning.

Comment: Thanks @Anthony, I will go with your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

This is a late post but recently the limit got increased to 15 minutes.

Comment: Doesn't help people who need it to run 20 minutes, lol. They should just remove it and let you specify whatever you want.